# django: need to design models/forms for a 'multiple level nested' structures

Tags: python, django

Assume some Company with Employees. There are Name and Contact information bound to each Employee. Each Contact contains Street and Phones fields. 
What I want is a page which lists employees within a company. But everything must be listed as forms. Because I want to be able to modify the particular Employee information and the most important - I want to be able to add new Employees (clicking a button "Add new employee" must add a new empty "Employee form"). As well as it must allow to add a new phone number to the existing Employee's Contact information any time. 
The data model looks like:

```
--Company
----Employee1
------Name
------Contact
--------Street
--------Phones
----------Phone1
----------Phone2
----Employee2
------Name
------Contact
--------Street
--------Phones
----------Phone1
----------Phone2
----------Phone3
...
```

Could someone please help to design Models and Forms for such a task? Your help is very much appreciated. Many thanks!

P.S. Forgot to mention that I want all the data "collected" in the Company object at the end of the day. I mean when I serialize c = Comapany.objects.all()[0] on the back end the entire employee information must be visible, like c.employees[0].contact.phones[0] must be the first employee's first phone number. Thanks.

P.P.S.
That is not the case that I'm just forwarding my project. This is just an hypothetical example I'd created to present the problem. I'm a django newbie and trying to understand how the framework gets things rolling. 
I've spent lot of time on this. I've found several ways to go, but no one got me to the end. For instance, a wonderful blog about nested formsets http://yergler.net/blog/2013/09/03/nested-formsets-redux/ helped with forms and rendering. But, it solved only the half of the problem. The data like I mentioned above is not "being collected" into an object. At the end of the day I want to serialize a Company object and save it in yaml format using pyyaml (see my previous post [django: want to have a form for dynamically changed sequence data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27602294/django-want-to-have-a-form-for-dynamically-changed-sequence-data)). 
Django is perfect with "static" models and forms, ModelForms are awesome. But what if your model needs to be changed dynamically? No standard way to go. Either no appropriate documentation nor I could find a one. Thus, I'd like to hear how experts imagine the solution for such a problem.

Comment: Please see my updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from django.db import models


class _Contact(object):
    pass


class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    @property
    def employees(self):
        return self.employee_set.prefetch_related('phones').order_by('-created_at')


class Phone(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    phones = models.ManyToManyField('Phone', through='EmployeePhone', blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)

    @property
    def contact(self):
        _contact = _Contact()
        _contact.street = self.street
        _contact.phones = self.phones.order_by('-employeephone__created_at')

        return _contact


class EmployeePhone(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
    phone = models.ForeignKey(Phone)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

However, you should just use `employee.street` and `employee.phones`. `employee.contact` is redundant.

Comment: Many thanks for the response. I liked your idea of "transparent contact". But my problem is more in binding forms to such kind of models. Could you please give any ideas how forms should look like for this models?